# Transit visa requirement for Dublin when flying on separate tickets

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas, ireland, dublin

My brother is traveling from India to Canada and I accidentally booked two separate tickets. One ticket is from India to Dublin via Doha and the second ticket is from Dublin to Calgary. He does not have any checked bag so does not need to collect his bag.

Does he require any type of visa to transit through Dublin?

Comment: Are you an Indian or a Canadian citizen?

Comment: What time do his flights arrive and depart [Irish immigration transit](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/)?

Comment: Indian citizen and arrival time is 13:40 with a 23 hr layover

Answer (score 1):

A 23-hour layover means he needs a visa.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true) Transit Without Visa

> Passengers transiting through Dublin (DUB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country. They must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from Terminal 2, and
> - be transiting between 04:00 and 16:00 on the same calendar day, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

See also [Irish Immigration visa advice](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/), which states:

> Transiting overnight – all Irish airports close at night and passengers are required to pass through border control.

You can also check using the full itinerary and passenger details on [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/)

Comment: OP should note of the 10-12 week lead time for an Irish visa in Canda

Comment: In addition, since this is a self-transfer, the first airline is very likely to ask that the passenger have the necessary paperwork to **enter** Ireland, whatever the timing and even if they have only carry-on luggage. Finally, the flights from Doha arrive in Terminal 1 and the flight to Calgary departs from Terminal 1, which also means a visa is required (no airside transit in Terminal 1, everybody has to go through passport control).